Spark's BloomFilter's bitSize is not matching what the given bitSize
I have two questions about using BloomFilter with Spark.
I'm trying to build a BloomFilter from a DataFrame in Databricks 15.4/Spark 3.5, using Spark's DataFrameStatFunctions. It Create's a org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilter  instance.
val bfExpectedItems = <?>
val bfBitSize = 8L * 1024 * 1024 * 100

val bf1 = spark.sql("SELECT client_id FROM d_clientids WHERE updated_at > TIMESTAMP('2024-10-01')").stat.bloomFilter(
  colName="client_id"
  , expectedNumItems = bfExpectedItems
  , numBits = bfBitSize
)

The issue is that the size (bitSize) of BloomFilter doesn't match given numBits:
> bf1.bitSize
bf1: org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilter = org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl@e200002b
res3: Long = 67108864

Why is that? I'm setting something wrong?
My second question is that I want to share the BloomFilter with other (some non-Spark) applications. Would that be possible to load the output binary with a different library and expect the same predictable behaviour across different libs/applications?

wrt the bloom bitsize your inputs are the recommended size.  Internally the spark bloom uses this initial bitsize with it's BitArray and the resulting BitArray is what is used to return the bitSize:
long bitSize() {
  return (long) data.length * Long.SIZE;
}

in terms of re-use you can re-use the BloomFilterImpl directly.
You cannot expect to use a different library and algorithm and expect the same behaviour.
